# Ubuntu CPU Fan at 2200 RPM and CPU top at 90°C

Tags: 14.04, cpu, overheating, fan, temperature

I have a problem with my CPU heat. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 (64bit) and I have issues with the cooling. I know it might be a hardware issue, but I've checked, the fan is running and in my GUI I use the command "sensors" which shows me a RPM of 2200 and a CPU temperature of 60°C while I'm not running any software. This seems to be really mysterious.

However, if I start my IDE (Eclipse), Firefox and Chromium at the same time, the CPU temp goes up to 75-90° Celsius. I doubt that this is common for a system with 16 GB RAM, an i7 Processor and an Intel water cooling system and I also never had some issues like this before when I was running Ubuntu 12.04 or 13.04.

**Fan Speed**

At 60°C it's at 1300 RPM, and after start up Eclipse and Firefox it's at approximately 2200 RPM and between 75°C - 90°C depending on how many windows and IDE's I've opened.

If I use the "top" command, there are just few processes like Xorg or Compiz which are taking up to 10% CPU usage at maximum, during the time I'm not running any software.

I have tried to upgrade the Linux kernel, where I failed. After upgrading, I wasn't able to boot anymore so I tried to remove the new kernel from the boot directory and updated my grub file to an old entry, which works fine now, but still with the temperature issue.

My NVIDIA drivers is also up to date, which dropped some issues I had before with the CPU load. So it can't be a problem with the graphic card.

How can I find out, where the problem is, or why my CPU gets that high temperatures, which I only should get while playing games with high end graphics and so on?

Did anyone have some similar issues before?

Comment: What is CPU model?

Comment: In reference to **cat /proc/cpuinfo/** I have an
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3820 CPU @ 3.60GHz.

To avoid uncertainty I will have to say that I'm using a tower Desktop computer, **not** a laptop.

Comment: Then what Cooler is used? Is it enough thermal paste in there?

Comment: It's an _Intel BXRTS2011LC, all-in-one Mini CPU Cooler, LGA2011_,
and as far as I can remember I used all of the thermal paste which was delivered with the cooler.

Comment: @T-Erra, Could you post the full hw info (on http://paste.ubuntu.com/) `sudo lshw -short; sudo lshw -sanitize`.

Comment: Is the thermal paste old (more than a couple of years)? They don't last that long. If you have another OS installed, does the problem also occur there? Or with a live CD? Also, can you post the output of `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor`? Does the fan speed up when you load eclipse or does it stay at the same RPM?

Comment: @Sneetsher
[pastebin entry is here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7638025/)

Comment: @terdon
your command give me the output "_ondemand_".

I set up the computer one year ago and the expiration date on the thermal paste was up to two years or more as far as I can remember.

I will now give a try to an Ubuntu live CD and have a look if the same issues occur. 

And yes, the fan speeds up. At 60°C it's at 1300 RPM, and after start up Eclipse and Firefox it's at approximately 2200 RPM and between 75°C - 90°C depending on how many windows and IDE's I've opened.

Comment: OK, then that's not the issue. Could you please [edit] your question and add the other details I asked for?

Comment: @terdon
I've tried now to reproduce the issues with a live CD and it's almost the same. 67°C while only a Firefox window was opened at a fan speed of 2100 RPM. 

I have now the following idea - flashing my ASUS P9X79 DELUXE to a newer BIOS version? But at the moment I have no clue about how to handle this within Linux, there is lack of information in reference to ASUS BIOS update using Linux OS. In this case I would have to open a new thread. However, would you recommend to try this way? Of course with a previously backed up system only.

Comment: The same as what? There is no problem with the live CD? 67°C is fine. If it is also heating up with the live CD and your fan is speeding up regardless, it does sound like a hardware issue. I doubt the BIOS update would help, I would go for cleaning the fan, making sure the cooling system is correctly installed and also applying new thermal paste, just in case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15083/discussion-between-t-erra-and-terdon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after updating my BIOS, installing the latest kernel headers and booting a live cd, I've figured out, that the problem was caused by something quite different. I disconnected every peripheral from my computer and booted it only connected to one monitor, instead of the three monitors I've always used. However, I had only an average temperature of 45°C and an average temperature of 55°C after connecting the second monitor. It turned out that after connecting the third monitor, my CPU was blowing up and I've decided now to use only two monitors in the future.

I also noticed that one power cable inside my computer case wasn't connected properly.

Thanks anyway for your help @terdon , Ruslan and Sneetsher.